# Voice of turn by turn navigation alternating between male and female

Tags: google-maps, text-to-speech

Sometimes the voice will be the female voice of Google text-to-speech and sometimes it will be the one from SVOX TTS, which is a different one. What should be causing them to alternate and how can I make it stop?